# PSQL13 - ERROR could not map dynamic shared memory segment

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

This the error i get after a statement that worked before, something broke at run time, what could it be?

```
STATEMENT:  SELECT * FROM "hep_proto_1_call"  WHERE (create_date between $1 AND $2 AND ( (protocol_header->>'captureId')::int = $3 )) LIMIT 2000
 ERROR:  could not map dynamic shared memory segment
 ERROR:  could not map dynamic shared memory segment
LOG:  background worker "parallel worker" (PID 262853) exited with exit code 1
LOG:  background worker "parallel worker" (PID 262854) exited with exit code 1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you get the error every time you execute the statement? One workaround is to set `max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 0`.

Comment: Yes it does.

whats thats workaround do?

Comment: The workaround disables parallel query. Then no dynamic shared memory segments for data exchange between the parallel workers are created, and the error won't happen. Your long running queries will become slower, but the overall throughput increases.

Comment: I see thank you.

If would like to fix this and not use a workaround, how would you suggest ill start?

Comment: Difficult. Reading the code, it looks like you should get this error only if the shared memory segment was removed before you get to map it. Is the CPU overloaded so that a worker is very slow? Are there too many active connections, so that the contention on the `DynamicSharedMemoryControlLock` is too high?